# Node js when is good time to use Buffer

Tags: node.js

I am learning nodejs and come cross the buffer Class. looks like it's a raw memory allocation outside the V8 heap. Wondering when it's a good situation to use buffer rather than use transitional string or array. is it purely for the sake of performance to use buffer?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_buffers.htm

Comment: Whenever you have data which doesn't have specific encoding scheme, blobs.

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less, yes. `Buffer` is very low-level since it abstracts `node::Buffer`. You use it for reading binary data and can also treat it as typed, which is very efficient. Whereas arrays might coerce. Those things are what JS naturally is quite bad at and therefore `v8` doesn't seem to be the best place to do them.

Maybe it's rather `Buffer` vs. `streams`:

`Buffer`s API is more straightforward and less verbose. It takes some time to setup `streams` properly. Also it's control flow is easier when you want to do just sequential stuff for low and mid sized data.